# Pandas: Clean way to calculate running error based on boolean column of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that is sourced from a JMeter report.  The index is a time series.  There is a column called "success" that is true if the underlying sample was successful, and false otherwise.

[image]

So I have two steps here.  The first is I need a running count of the number of rows where success is false.  Then I need to divide the number by the number of samples so far:

[image]

I solved the first step by inverting the success column, converting to an int, and then running cumsum

`df['fail_count'] = (~df['success']).astype(int).cumsum()`

Is there a cleaner way to solve the second piece, dividing by the number of samples, than by add ing a static column of one, adding a cumsum column over that one, then doing the division?

```
    df['fail_count'] = (~df['success']).astype(int).cumsum()
    df['one'] = 1
    df['sample_num'] = df['one'].cumsum()
    df['error_rate'] = df['fail_count'].div(df['sample_num'])
```

Comment: Please don't paste data as screenshots next time. Please read this thread: stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391

Answer (score 2):

Just perform vectorized division directly:

```
df['error_rate'] = df['fail_count'] / np.array(range(1, len(df) + 1))
```

Alternatively, you can also do the following provided your index is the default `[0,1,2,3,...]`. If it is not, perform `df.reset_index(inplace=True)` before the calculation will get the job done, but unnecessarily messing with the index is of course not recommended.

```
df['error_rate'] = df['fail_count'] / (df.index + 1)
```

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={
        "fail_count": [0,0,1,1,2,2]
    }
)

df['error_rate'] = df['fail_count'] / np.array(range(1, len(df) + 1))
# or
# df['error_rate'] = df['fail_count'] / (df.index + 1)
```

**Output**

```
df
Out[15]: 
   fail_count  error_rate
0           0    0.000000
1           0    0.000000
2           1    0.333333
3           1    0.250000
4           2    0.400000
5           2    0.333333
```

Answer (score 1):

To compute *fail_count* use:

```
df['fail_count'] = (~df.success).cumsum()
```

Almost like in your code sample, but remember that *bool* is actually
a subtype of *int* (*True* is *1* and *False* is *0*) so can compute
the sum (also cumulative) directly from a *bool* column.

And as far as *error_rate* is concerned, I see 2 simple solutions:

1. If you can rely on the index (a sequence of numbers from *0*),
   run:

   ```
    df['error_rate'] = df.fail_count / (df.index + 1)
   ```
2. Otherwise you can generate such a temporary index of proper size,
   starting from *1* (instead of *0*), so you don't need "*+ 1*" later,
   and use it just the same way:

   ```
    df['error_rate'] = df.fail_count / pd.RangeIndex(1, df.index.size + 1)
   ```

Decide yourself which variant to choose.

So is is enough to use just the 2 above instructions instead of your 4.